# Are there any network switch platforms for Linux/BSD?

Tags: linux, networking, embedded, hardware

There's plenty of barebone PCs/servers optimized for building custom Linux/BSD based routers, VPN servers or firewalls and in general various L3 devices. However I couldn't really find anything about L2 devices with hardware switch ASICs. While I know it's possible to just use bridging it's not really practical solution.

Are there available some devices with built-in hardware switch chips that are optimized for running Linux distros like pfSense or WRT derivatives using `switchdev` driver to build managed switch?

Comment: pfSense is built on FreeBSD, not Linux.

Comment: We're allowed to make hardware recommendations here?

Comment: @Rob it's not really question about hardware recommendation itself but about `switchdev` driver adoption in hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the term `whitebox switches` for your searches. There are some vendors/distributions in that area.